# NodeJS - Will TCP Net and HTTP Server Both Crash on Error?

Tags: node.js, http, amazon-web-services, tcp, crash

I am running a NodeJS server that uses both:

- net TCP server on one port (connection to telematics hardware devices that send data messages to the server)
- and a HTTP server on another port (to run the web app platform)

These are both running through the one server.js file.

If there is an error on one side, will both crash and go down, or will the other still run independently?

Running on AWS EC2 Ubuntu, using forever module to keep alive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're both started under the same process (and you do *not* have appropriate error handling in place), then the answer is yes. You can have your code structured however you want (e.g. the tcp server in one file and the http in another), but if the servers are both started by the same node process, they will both go down if the process dies due to unhandled `error` events, uncaught exceptions, stack overflow, out of memory errors, etc.

Comment: I guess it follows then that even if it were two separate processes, if there were 1000 connected users to the web side, any unhandled error by one user would force the entire process to restart and all other users would have their web app crash. Is this then a reason to not use node for the http side and use something like php instead?